# MariaDB дамп и большие объемы

Tags: mariadb, dump

Имеется большие БД весом не меньше 10гб. При их дампе сервер повисает, как можно более мягче дампить данные без большой потери производительности?

Comment: а почему не настроить репликацию и делать дамп с второго сервера (slave). А в свободное время второй сервер может помогать распределять нагрузку.

Comment: Так перед репликацией надо сделать копию базы ведь на вторую машину. А как вы делаете дамп, что сервер повисает? mysqldump в связке с gzip прекрасно справляется с такими объемами

Comment: @vanchester, репликация сама сделает копию, при этом в сам процесс репликации уже должен быть заложен "мягкий" алгоритм копирования, чтобы ненароком не завалить базу-источник.

Comment: @Fike, я думаю, вы не правы, по крайней мере в отношении MySQL (MariaDB). Репликация строится на основе бинарных логов, которые создаются только после включения репликации на мастере и потом забираются репликами. Не включена репликация - нет этих логов. В эти логи попадают все запросы, которые изменяют структуру или данные БД.

Во всех руководствах перед включением репликации (специально сейчас несколько просмотрел, удивясь информации от вас) БД на мастере останавливается или переводится в ReadOnly, вручную копируется на слейв, включается механизм репликации и мастер выводится в боевой режим.

Comment: как пруф к моим словам

http://habrahabr.ru/post/56702/

раздел "Переносим данные"

Comment: @vanchester, да, наврал

Comment: Как часто очищается бинарный лог, не сожрет ли он все пространство?

Comment: за срок жизни логов отвечает параметр expire_logs_days в my.cnf

Comment: Спасибо. По поводу репликации, в ответ ее и я бы пометил как верный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю несколько вариантов.

Способ 1. Скопировать файлы баз на новый сервер. Обычно они лежат в /var/lib/mysql. Т.е. на новом сервере устанавливаете MySQL (или MariaDB), останавливаете его и просто заменяете те файлы, которые создались в /var/lib/mysql на файлы со старой машины. После запуска он будет работать с этими базами. Еще эту же задачу можно решить, прописав другой путь к базам в my.cnf

Способ 2. Воспользоваться утилитой mysqldump. Она создает дамп БД на столько быстро, на сколько это возможно. Я пользуюсь такой командой

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbname | gzip > dump.sql.gz
```

Если задача позволяет сдампить только несколько таблиц, после dbname их можно перечислить.
Восстановление будет выглядеть так:

```
gunzip <dump.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p dbname
```

10 ГБ - вполне реальная цифра для этого способа, но придется подождать (думаю, около 30-50 минут на дамп и столько же на восстановление). Я пользуюсь именно этим способом.

Способ 3. Если на сервере есть настроенные php и какой-нибудь веб-сервер, можно воспользоваться скриптом [sypex dumper](http://sypex.net/ru/products/dumper/downloads/). Работает довольно быстро, имеет ряд удобных инструментов. Позволяет делать как полный бэкап, так и только выбранных таблиц. При выполнении операций есть подробная информация о том, что сейчас выполняется, показывает процент оставшегося объема операций. Для восстановления нужно будет воспользоваться им же.

Comment: То что вы предложили, это обычный способ дампа, мне он не подходит, цель не просто сдампить данные, а сдампить данные незаметно для процессов использующих sql сервер и которые повисают во время дампа, залагивают. Минут на 10-15.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант попробовать по таблицам. Но если их много - то это жесть).

Comment: около 50 сцепленных друг с другом таблиц, весь их иногда очень велик.